# Customising SharePoint 2013 Workflow Task Form

Tags: 2013, workflow, visual-studio, custom-form, task-list

I have a SharePoint list that has an attached SP 2013 Workflow. I plan to customize the task form using Visual Studio 2012. The idea is that for each task, I will ask the user to input some values then submit (which will save the values back to my SP list). Upon submitting it will route to another user and ask for other input, and so on.

My question is how do I customize the task form using Visual Studio? Is there any server side code available, based from what I have read SharePoint 2013 Workflow is focused on client side coding.

I am having a difficult time finding the right reference materials, hopefully someone here can help to suggest some good reference materials and provide a heads-up in customizing task form.

Comment: Did you develop the workflow yourself in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes I did use Visual studio to start creating my 2013 workflow

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom task forms in Visual Studio. The basic steps are:

- Create a tasks list
- Create a new content type that inherits from Workflow Task (SharePoint 2013)
- Create site columns for each of the fields you want to appear in your custom task form
- Add the site columns to your content type
- Add the content type to your tasks list
- Set the tasks list as the tasks list used by your workflow
- When creating the task in your workflow, set the *Task Content Type* option to your newly create content type.

See [here](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/sharepoint-2013-workflow-custom-tasks) for an explanation and guide.