# Modifying Task Forms

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, tasks

Is it possible that I can modify the task form when I assign a task in a workflow? I would like to customize my form fields and hide some of the current fields related to a "Task" content type.

Comment: are you checked this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159438/customising-sharepoint-2013-workflow-task-form

Comment: I had not seen that, but I have no experience with Visual Studio. Is that the only way to go about customizing the forms?

Comment: without VS check this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdesigner/2012/09/14/how-to-manipulate-the-task-form-with-sharepoint-designer-for-new-task-actions/

Comment: @M.Qassas - I followed the instructions and added the new Site Content Type to the Task List, and when I changed it within the workflow and attempted to run it, I got this error:

An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.ArgumentException: ContentTypeId